# Mapear classes que herdam o Id de outra classe Entity - EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Preciso mapear as classes Pessoa e Filial com relacionamento um-para-um, onde uma pessoa será apenas uma filial e uma filial estará atrelada a apenas uma pessoa, (Uma PK em Id Pessoa e PK/FK em Id Filial). O Entity Framework Core está se confundindo e colocando PK no Id Filial e FK em Pessoa.
Eu criei uma classe chamada Entity que contém uma propriedade Id para todas herdarem dela. Acho que isso está provocando o problema.

```js
public abstract class Entity
    {
        public Guid Id { get; protected set; }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            var compareTo = obj as Entity;

            if (ReferenceEquals(this, compareTo)) return true;
            if (ReferenceEquals(null, compareTo)) return false;

            return Id.Equals(compareTo.Id);
        }

        public static bool operator ==(Entity a, Entity b)
        {
            if (ReferenceEquals(a, null) && ReferenceEquals(b, null))
                return true;

            if (ReferenceEquals(a, null) || ReferenceEquals(b, null))
                return false;

            return a.Equals(b);
        }

        public static bool operator !=(Entity a, Entity b)
        {
            return !(a == b);
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return (GetType().GetHashCode() * 907) + Id.GetHashCode();
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return GetType().Name + " [Id=" + Id + "]";
        }
    }
```

```js
 public class Pessoa : Entity
    {
       
        public virtual Filial Filial { get; private set; }

        protected Pessoa() { }

        public Pessoa( Guid id, PessoaNatureza pessoaNatureza)
        {
            Id = id;
            PessoaNatureza = pessoaNatureza;
        }
    }
```

```js
public class Filial : Entity    {
       
        public virtual Pessoa Pessoa { get; set; }

        protected Filial() { }

        public Filial(Guid id)
        {
            Id = id;
        }
    }
```

//Mapeamentos

```js
 public class FilialMap : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Filial>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Filial> builder)
        {
            builder.ToTable("tblFilial");

            builder.HasKey(f => f.Id);

           builder
                .HasOne(u => u.Pessoa)
                .WithOne(p => p.Filial)
                .HasConstraintName("FK_Pessoa_Filial")
                .IsRequired();

            builder.Property(f => f.Id)
                .ValueGeneratedNever()
                .HasColumnName("PessoaId")
                .IsRequired();

        }
    }
```

```js
public class PessoaMap : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Pessoa>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Pessoa> builder)
        {
            builder.ToTable("tblPessoa");

            builder.HasKey(p => p.Id);

            builder.Property(p => p.Id)
                .HasColumnName("PessoaId")
                .IsRequired()
                .ValueGeneratedNever();

            builder.Property(p => p.PessoaNatureza)
               .HasColumnName("PessoaNaturezaId")
               .IsRequired();


        }
    }
```

Comment: Tente fazer: builder.HasOne(u => u.Filial).WithOne(p => p.Pessoa).HasForeignKey<Filial>(b => b.FilialId); no mapeamento de Pessoa

Comment: Funcionou!!! Obrigado Gabriel! :)

Comment: Ah! comenta lá na pergunta para eu poder defini-la como resposta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você precisa fazer o mapeamento na configuração de Pessoas para ele criar corretamente:

```
...
builder.HasOne(u => u.Filial)
    .WithOne(p => p.Pessoa)
    .HasForeignKey<Filial>(b => b.FilialId); 
...
```